# UIPanGestureRecognizer in UITableView does not work on iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, ios8

I have a `UITableView`, which contains cells with `UIPanGestureRecognizer`s. The works perfectly fine on iOS7, but does not work on iOS8. I have tried to implement several methods from the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, but I can't make it work.

This is how I have implemented my cells:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panning:)];
    self.panRecognizer.delegate = self;
    self.panRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    self.panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    [self.contentView addGestureRecognizer:self.panRecognizer];
}

-(void)panning:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    [self.dragDelegate dragCell:self isPanningForRecognizer:sender];
}

#pragma mark - UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    return YES;
}
```

This simply works on iOS7, but it does not work on iOS8.

I have tried implementing these methods aswell (even though it was not necessary on iOS7):

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer");
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"gestureRecognizerShouldBegin");
    return YES;
}
```

But my problem seems to be that  `gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` never gets called on iOS8. The only method that gets called on iOS8 is `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:` and even though I return `YES` is does not work.

I am open to approach this differently if you can come up with a another way to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like Apple changed something with the `contentView` of a `UITableViewCell` in iOS8. No matter how much I tried, I could not make it work on the `contentView`, but when I desperately tried to add the recognizer on a subview of the `contentView` it worked.

**EDIT:**

By further investigation I was using a xib file without a `contentView`. It was a standard `UIView` which was set to be my custom cell class. The problem seems to be that iOS7 adds the `contentView` automatically on top of other subviews, even if the `contentView` isn't the xib file. On the other hand iOS8 also does this, but the `contentView` was placed below my other subviews, which made it impossible for the touch events to get triggered.